# resolving Promises in express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

My `gethealth()` function contains chained promises. In version route, I want to return the object but I am currently getting pending promises in return. I am not sure how to resolve each Promise in my `systemHealth` object

```
export const version = (req, res) => {
  const systemHealth = gethealth()
  res.status(200).send(systemHealth)
}
```

result:

```
console.log(systemHealth)

[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
```

Comment: See the linked question's answers. You need to *consume* the promises. Since you're returning an array of them, the best way is probably `Promise.all`, which waits for them all to fulfill:

`export const version = (req, res) => {
  Promise.all(gethealth())
  .then(systemHealth => {
    res.status(200).send(systemHealth);
  });
}` (More readable: https://pastebin.com/W3t7vWvn)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder PERFECT this is just what I needed! If you answer the question. I will accept!